# How can I upload images to s3 in react native?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, expo

I am trying to upload local images from my react native app (i'm using expo) to an s3 bucket, but nothing seems to work.
I'm am using react-native-aws3 library, but Promise.then never gets called. It doesn't throw any error either.

This is the code:

```
const options = {
    bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    region: REGION,
    accessKey: AWS_USER_KEY,
    secretKey: AWS_PRIVATE_KEY,
    successActionStatus: 201

}

export async function uploadImage(imageUri, imageName, imageType) {
    const file = {
        uri: imageUri,
        name: imageName,
        type: "image/" + imageType
    }

    RNS3.put(file, options).then( (response) => {
            console.log("done")
            console.log(response)
            console.log(response.status)
    })
}
```

This is the Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1648118554991",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1648118551643",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the IAM user policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried following every tutorial I could find, but nothing seems to work. Do I have to do something else, like server side? or is there something wrong in the policies?

Answer (score 0):

To upload content to an Amazon S3 bucket, use the official AWS SDK for JavaScript. To use this SDK with React, look at this doc topic:

[Getting started in React Native](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-react-native.html)

To work with Amazon S3, see:

[Amazon S3 examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/s3-examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

code mentioned here works in "react-native": "0.68.2" 
your react native camera collects image uri something like this `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.lobb.agent/files/Pictures/image-e4047ca8-5df9-489d-ac86-2bcdf24cd3436728860500254451478.jpg`

following code does these steps

1. accepts your image uri
2. convert the image uri in to blob,
3. makes put request to s3 bucket

   ```
   const handleImageUpload = async () => {
     try {
       const resp = await fetch(yourImageURI); // 
       const imageBody = await resp.blob(); // conv uri to blob
       const result = await fetch(yourSignedURL, {
         method: 'PUT',
         body: imageBody,
      });
      console.log('result:', result);
    } catch (error) {
    console.log('error upload :', error);
    }
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

recently I applied the same functionality of uploading media on **`s3`**

I used [base64-arraybuffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-arraybuffer) for encodes and decodes base64 to and from ArrayBuffers and also using [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs) for filesystem access for **react-native** and also used [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk).

Here is the code that I used to upload media on **s3**.

**# My Bucket Component:**

```
import {S3} from 'aws-sdk';
import {BUCKET, ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, SIGNATURE_VERSION } from '@env';

export const s3bucket = new S3({
  accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  Bucket: BUCKET,
  signatureVersion: SIGNATURE_VERSION,
});
```

**# Upload Media Component:**

```
import fs from 'react-native-fs';
import {s3bucket} from './Constants';
import {decode} from 'base64-arraybuffer';

export const uploadMedia = async obj => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let contentType = obj.mime;
    let contentDeposition = 'inline;filename="' + obj.path + '"';
    const base64 = await fs.readFile(obj.path, 'base64');
    const arrayBuffer = decode(base64);
    s3bucket.createBucket(async () => {
      const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET,
        Key: obj.path,
        Body: arrayBuffer,
        ContentDisposition: contentDeposition,
        ContentType: contentType,
      };
      s3bucket.upload(params, async (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  });
};
```

**obj** is the full media object that we get when we pick media from gallery and **obj.mime** is the type of media.